# aws sagemaker error on Create labelling job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker, aws-policies

I uploaded a csv file to S3, created a role with S3FullAccess and SageMakerFullAccess. While creating labelling job, I chose Automated data setup and chose the bucket that the csv had uploaded. Then Data type: text and chose the IAM Role. Then clicked "Complete data set up"
then I get below error message

```
Connection error
There was an issue with your input data setup. Ground Truth could not setup a connection with your dataset in S3. Please check your input data setup and try again, or use the manual data setup option. Network Failure Request id:xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

No idea why this error message shows up... Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It was the permission issue.
Refer this link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-security-permission-console-access.html